# tkinter.entry and NameErrors.

Tags: python

I am currently coding a GUI for a palindrome-detector but I have run into some problems. I can launch the program and the GUI appears to be fine. All buttons work except the essential one: Testa Palindrom (translates to Test Palindrome).

Whenever I click that button, I get a NameError: global name 'palindromentry' is not defined.

Below you will find the entire code but first a quick explanation of what it does.

def ordnaText lowers the text and fixes it for the check.
def testap tests whether it is a palindrome or not using a for-loop.
def visaResultat shows the result (this can be see in the label1.config).

My question is: Why am I getting this error? I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
def main():

    gui()
    tkinter.mainloop()

def gui():
    main_window = tkinter.Tk()
    top_frame = tkinter.Frame()
    mid_frame = tkinter.Frame()
    bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()


    main_window.title("Palindromdetektor")
    main_window.geometry("400x400")



    label1 = tkinter.Label(top_frame, text = "Skriv in ett palindrom nedan för att testa det!",
                                bg = "green", width = 60, height = 6)
    button1 = tkinter.Button(mid_frame, text = "Testa palindrom", height = 3, width = 22,
                                bg = "Purple", command = mainaction) 

    button2 = tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text= "Instruktioner", height = 3, width = 22,
                                bg = "Purple", command = messagebox) 

    button3 = tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text ="Spara palindrom", height = 3, width = 22,
                                bg = "Purple") #command = sparapalindrom) 

    button4 = tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text ="Avsluta programmet", height = 3, width = 22,
                                bg = "Purple", command=main_window.destroy)



    palindromentry = tkinter.Entry(mid_frame, width = 67)
    palindromentry.pack()

    top_frame.pack()
    mid_frame.pack()
    bottom_frame.pack()

    label1.pack()
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()
    button3.pack()
    button4.pack()



def ordnaText(text):
        nytext = ("") 
        fixadText = text.lower() 
        for i in fixadText: 
            if i.isalnum(): 
                nytext = (nytext + i) 
        return nytext 



def testap(nytext):
        palindrom  = True 
        for i in range (0, len(nytext)):
            if (nytext[i]) != (nytext[len(nytext)-i-1]): 
                palindrom = False 
        return palindrom

def visaResultat(palindrom):
    if palindrom:
            label1.config(text="Ja, detta är ett palindrom!", bg="green")
    else:
            label1.config(text="Nej, detta är inte ett palindrom!", bg="red")

def messagebox():
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Hjälp", "Detta är ett program som testar vare sig en text är ett palindrom eller inte.\n \
Skriv in din text i rutan och tryck på Testa Palindrom-knappen så får du se ditt resultat högst upp.\n \
Om du vill avsluta programmet klickar du på knappen som heter Avsluta programmet.\n \
Detta program är kodat av Olof Unge som nås via mail: olofunge@hotmail.com.\n \
Tack för att du använder detta program!")

#def sparapalindrom():
 #   try:
  #      if palindrom:
   #         myfile = open("palindrom.txt", "a")
    #        myfile.write(text\n)
     #       myfile.close()
      #  else:
       #     label1.config(text="Du kan bara spara godkända palindrom.")
    # except IOError:
     #   label1.config(text="Kunde inte hitta / skapa filen.")



def mainaction():
    global text
    text = palindromentry.get()
    ordnaText(text)
    testap(ordnaText(text))
    visaResultat(testap(ordnaText(text)))

main()
```

I would appreciate very much if you could stick to topic and not comment anything else because everything else works fine. Thank you very much!

Best regards.

THIS IS CODED IN PYTHON 3.0

Comment: It's not really a fel men du borde inte mix english med svenska even in code. Makes it harder to read. Just saying. ;)

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`palindromentry` is defined in the `gui` function.  As such, it's scope is limited to that single function.  When you click the button, the `mainaction` function is called, but it knows nothing of the `gui` function's scope.

There are a few options here (in order of my preferences):

1. Make all of this stuff a class so that you can share the state between function calls
2. move the definition of `mainaction` into the `gui` function (It needs to be defined before the button which does the action ...).
3. declare palindromentry as `global` in `gui`

Comment: So it should be defined in the mainaction function?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a class?

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: @user1916173 -- See options 2 and 3 ;-)

Comment: Re: #2, it shouldn't matter if you declare `palindromentry` before or after defining the function. Just declare it before calling the function.

Comment: @Kevin -- I didn't think it should matter.  I wasn't sure how the functions closure would be constructed in python3.x.  I didn't feel like playing around with it or thinking too hard :-p.  I was just worried something may have changed with closures because of the addition of the `nonlocal` keyword in python3.x